# How can I store/backup Virtual Box's Virtual PC's data/config on another drive?

Tags: virtualbox

I can create virtual hdd's on a separate drive, but how can I do the same for the virtual PC's data/config so that say I do a format, I can restore all my Virtual PC's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://superuser.com/questions/17340/how-to-easily-port-virtualbox-machines) page:

> You can just copy the files inside the directories you mentioned, that is, the virtual harddisk (.vdi) and the xml-based description of the virtual machine. I did this twice, even cross plattform (a XP geust from an OS X host to a Windows XP host, and an Ubuntu guest from a Windows Vista Host to an OS X host) and it worked fine

Or result to the [import](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-import) and the [export](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-export) sections of the user manual. :)